# AltGr+O special character not working vscode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, altgr

I'm using vscode on Windows with my German Dvorak keyboard layout. I have set my `AltGr` + `O` to be `(`. When I start vscode and try to use this combination it works for like 2 seconds or so. Then I have to press `AltGr+O` twice for it to enter `(`. If I only press it once, the whole application freezes, including windowbar, and it only resumes to work when I press it again. The combination works in Windows and, for example, Firefox.

I should add, that `AltGr` + `E` for `(`, and other special characters involving `AltGr` work perfectly fine.

I have made sure that none of my hotkeys interfere with it and also checked it without extensions.

Here are the keyboard shortcuts logs:

- [keyboard log for the first press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqA0P.png)
- [keyboard log for the second press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcFK5.png)

Let me know if my keyboard layout `.klc` file would be of use.

Thank you in advance